# no crontab for root - using an empty one crontab: installing new crontab "/tmp/crontab.xxx":1:

Tags: linux

After I use

```
crontab -e
```

And in the file edit it with:

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /Home/Controller/xy28.php
```

When I esc(`:wq`) from the file. I got the error:

> no crontab for root - using an empty one
>   crontab: installing new crontab
>   "/tmp/crontab.oD7RUA":1: bad hour
>   errors in crontab file, can't install.
>   Do you want to retry the same edit?

How to solve it?

Comment: visually that looks fine, copypasting the line from the question here works with crontab. Check that you don't have any funny or invisible characters like non-breaking spaces there. Since the error comes from the hours field, it's probably not about a windows-style linebreak, even though that's one common problem source.

Comment: what about trying a arbitrary minute (e.g. 3) ? your line looks OK, doas man 5 crontab allow for */3 syntax ?

Comment: @Archemar Our phper says it is not execute success, but in `cat /var/log/cron` I find there is executed, and the path now is correct. `xy28.php` is corrrected. if there should consider of thread-safety?

Comment: @Archemar I know the 3 means 3 minutes, but how about the first `*` and the other `* * * *` means?